# Identify user's location and include it in the response sent to my app on MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, gps, microsoft-teams, userlocation

We have an app on Microsoft Teams that sends messages to a group of users and expects a response to the message from them. Along with the users' responses, we want to get their location. Can we get the user’s location and publish it in our app on MS Teams using graph API?
Is there any other API available to achieve this?

Comment: Please check these docs to integrate location capabilities with your app  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/device-capabilities-overview, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/location-capability?tabs=mobile%2Cteamsjs-v2#location-apis

Comment: You can also use graph API /users to [get users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) city please check the following command. The following command returns user's display name, postal code and city. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1640f0b5-50be-47a9-98c7-3dad61079bef?$select=displayName,postalCode,city - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT583.png

Comment: Just to clarify, by location I meant we need the GPS coordinates

Comment: Please check my first comment, getLocation(LocationProps, (error: SdkError, location: Location) => void) Fetches current user coordinates or allows user to choose location on map. Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/location-capability?tabs=mobile%2Cteamsjs-v2#location-apis,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.location?view=msteams-client-js-1.13.1#@microsoft-teams-js-microsoftteams-location-getlocation